# How to find polygons in 2D map given just a contour marker?

Tags: java, geometry, dbscan

So given a a 2D array of points, how do I find all polygons where every point of the polygon coordinate is (diagonally adjecant) to the next one?

For example this image:

[image]

I am interested in flooding the area enclosed by a closed point chain (every coordinate is adjecant to the next one forming a closed loop), regarding of its shape. I am not interested in identifying individual polygons, only filling the polygon. Every point has a label (1, 2, 3, + etc) where 0 is unset So for example:

- Yellow is a square where the center point is getting filled.
- Orange is a bigger square but the corners are only diagonally adjecant to eachother.
- Green is a shape where if you follow the point chain, you cannot just always turn right.
- Red is not a valid shape as its point chain is not closed.
- Blue is not a valid shape as its point chain is not closed, edge does not close it.

I've looked at convex hull but that gives me the hull of all points which is not what I am interested in.

Couple rules:
- Every point has a value from 1 to 10.
- A region can only be filled if the **closed** pointchain is of the same label.
- Point chains that are not closed are not valid regions.
- x/y coordinates of the points are whole numbers.

I'm implementing it in Java and I've tried this: https://github.com/Merowech/java-concave-hull/blob/master/ConcaveHull.java

But given a map like this:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0
```

It gives me this as output:

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0
```

I've also tried DBSCAN which ended up not being able ignore small clusters next to a big cluster of the same label

Update:

A simple flood fill would not work as the requirement is that all surrounding pixels of the polygon are of the same value:

```
    public static void floodFill(int[][] map, int fill, Point loc) {
        if (loc.x < 0 || loc.x >= map[0].length || loc.y < 0 || loc.y >= map.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        int old = map[loc.y][loc.x];

        // Checks trivial case where loc is of the fill color
        if (fill == old) return;

        floodLoop(map, loc.x, loc.y, fill, old);
    }

    // Recursively fills surrounding pixels of the old color
    private static void floodLoop(int[][] map, int x, int y, int fill, int old) {

        int[] aux = {255, 255, 255, 255};

        // finds the left side, filling along the way
        int fillL = x;
        do {
            map[y][fillL] = fill;
            fillL--;
        } while (fillL >= 0 && map[y][fillL] == old);
        fillL++;

        // find the right right side, filling along the way
        int fillR = x;
        do {
            map[y][fillR] = fill;
            fillR++;
        } while (fillR <= map[0].length - 1 && map[y][fillR] == old);
        fillR--;

        // checks if applicable up or down
        for (int i = fillL; i <= fillR; i++) {
            if (y > 0 && map[y-1][i] == old) floodLoop(map, i, y - 1,
                    fill, old);
            if (y < map.length - 1 && map[y+1][i] == old) floodLoop(
                    map, i, y + 1, fill, old);
        }
    }

    public static int[][] map = new int[][]
    {
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},

    };

    public static int[][] expected_result = new int[][]
    {
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},

    };


    private static void printMap(int[][] map)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < map.length; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < map[0].length; x++)
            {
                System.out.print(map[y][x] +  " ,");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] copy = map.clone();

        floodFill(copy, 1, new Point(0,0));

        printMap(copy);
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates both, your issue and your effort to solve it. BTW which Java framework are you using? Swing?

Comment: I am not using any Java framework. The DBSCAN was from the apache math3 library.

Comment: I'm not familiar with either DBSCAN or math3, but anyone who does, will need to see your code. Please post it as code-formatted text inside your question and not in external links

Comment: @Wesley If you are not interested in the polygon itself, I'm pretty sure that using a specialized [4-direction flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) would be much easier than actually finding the polygon. Have you considered using it? You could perform the flood fill several times using different colors and checking if the fill was touching only one polygon or not.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé I've added an example that I couldn't get to work. I'm only interested in filling in tiles by the value that they are fully enclosed with and only if that value is the same.

Comment: @Wesley A simple flood fill won't work. Fill with a dummy color along all edges that has value 0. Then, find a cell that has value 0 for which one of his neighbor has a color. Fill it with the polygon color. Repeat it for every 0 cell. Then, redo the flood fill on the borders with value 0. There are some exceptions when an area is bounded by two colors. In these case, you detect it during the fill and revert the fill. That's pretty much what Anony-Mousse said in its answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not a density-based clustering problem**. So DBSCAN is simply not the right algorithm for this task.

What you want is a pretty simple *flood fill* approach. Identify the outside, fill it white. Find a pixel that isn't filled, but has a neighbor. Begin a flood fill with the neighbors color.

Except for some corner cases (touching shapes) that is probably all you need. These can likely be detected during the floor fill and filled white instead.

Comment: The hard requirement is that the value of the pixels that are not set to empty (0) have to be of the same value in order for the shape to be filled.

Comment: Easy. Do the flood fill, but check if you find more than one neighbor color.

Comment: I'm sure there is a more efficient algorithm than looping over every label possibility, doing a flood fill for every area that is set to 0 and check if the floodfill is valid.

Comment: You can trivially do the validity checking during the fill. The fill is cheap, and you will only need very few fills, usually around n+1 if you have n labels. How much cheaper do you expect this to become? Did you benchmark?

Comment: as additional speedup you can limit the fill to the bounding boxes of each label, but I doubt that makes much of a difference. Essentially every pixel will be filled once, the runtime is O(n) for n pixels total.